# ASP.NET, MVC, Entity Framework and understanding of models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I faced with misunderstanding

1. I use EntityFramework in my project with CodeFirst methodology
2. Please correct me if I think incorrect

Models which are using for Entity Framework and describing structure of DB and Models which are using for View should be located separately or use [NotMapped] attribute?

For example:

Now i have below models:

```
public class Title
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
}

public class UserType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Title> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Model "Title"  I use in my controller to view/edit/create new records

And the same can be done in separated modelView file?

For example:

```
public class TitleViewModel
{
    public virtual Title Titles { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and then  below code can be removed from "Title" model?

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual ICollection<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }

public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Your view model should be `public class TitleViewModel { public int? ID { get; set; } [Required]public int? SelectedUserType { get; set; } public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserTypes { get; set; } }` assuming your generating a dropdownlist to select a `UserType`

Comment: The objects reflect DB structure used in ORM (in this case EF) can be used for model structuring though it's not recommended because those objects are not `plain`. In other words, they contain other mapping logic besides data structure of the model. In a n-layer architecture, it makes the higher layers tightly coupled to the data acess/repository layer which is using a certain ORM library and in a n-tier architecture, it isn't good for serializing those objects from process to process. Using data transfer objects (or whatever they call `plain` objects nowadays) could be a choice.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : **model for persistance should be separated from model for display**.

According to the **Separation Of Concerns** (SOC) pattern, they have different responsibilities, then should be separated.
Moreover, in most cases, model for display is **different** from model for persistance (especially with EF which is linked to a relational database).
You can use [**Automapper**](http://automapper.org/) to convert from (and back) one layer to the other.
This way, properties and methods are **not mixed** in a "two-headed" model.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use containment in a view model whereby you are containing the EF model, this is the best design because the containing viewmodel allows you to add function, fields and properties.

In addition you can add (contain) other EF models too. This is the implementation of "Favor composition over inheritance"

Comment: `You can use the EF models for the view`, this is not good idea at all for the production application, because it violate the `separation of concerns` principal.